# Lambda linq repeated information

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the next code that i developed myself. It works, but if in the XML has 3 records, it will show the three records, but all of them will have the same information that the last one has.

```
//Load file and puts it on a IEnumerable interface
IEnumerable<MObject> MObjects = XDocument.Load(v_urlDataConnection)
.Element("MTestData").Descendants("book")
.Select(x => new MObject
{
Title = x.Element("title").Value,
Artist = x.Element("artist").Value,
Company = x.Element("company").Value,
Country = x.Element("country").Value,
Year = x.Element("year").Value,
Price = float.Parse(x.Element("price").Value)
}).ToList();
```

The xml is:

```
    <MTestData>
    <book>
        <title>Scenes</title>
        <artist>Dream Theater</artist>
        <company>Vertigo</company>
        <country>USA</country>
        <year>1999</year>
        <price>19.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
        <title>Falling</title>
        <artist>Dream Theater</artist>
        <company>3</company>
        <country>3</country>
        <year>3</year>
        <price>3</price>
  </book>
  <book>
        <title>Images and Words</title>
        <artist>Dream Theater</artist>
        <company>Elektra</company>
        <country>USA</country>
        <year>1991</year>
        <price>15</price>
  </book>
</MTestData>
```

Comment: you should change tag names to something like book1,book2 and book3.

Comment: Your code looks good and the results are fine. I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Nima, you mean like change the <book> an add for each a number? Like this: 
    <book1>
        <title>Scenes</title>
        <artist>Dream Theater</artist>
        <company>Vertigo</company>
        <country>USA</country>
        <year>1999</year>
        <price>19.99</price>
  </book1>
  <book2>
        <title>Falling</title>
        <artist>Dream Theater</artist>
        <company>3</company>
        <country>3</country>
        <year>3</year>
        <price>3</price>
  </book2>

Comment: @Robert, your xml is fine. You're downloading it from an url, so it's not even a good idea to change it. Please provide your `MObject` class declaration.

Comment: Ok, thanks you @Mihai. I found what is not working and is nothing about the linq  query I was using, thanks for the time you took for helping me :).

Comment: I agree with @Mihai the code works fine according to the given code  in the question

Comment: It was the way I declared the MObject, thanks to all of you :)

Comment: @Robert, I'm curious what went wrong. I've tried to declare MObject myself to try and reproduce your issue, but no luck :). Also, you're allowed to use an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) here. That is, you can have `.Select(x => new {...` without specifying the `MObject` and without needing to declare it. You'll get a list of objects with the properties listed in the `.Select` clause. I don't know if that would be better in your case, but I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: It was declared this way:
private static string v_title;
private static string v_artist; 

        public string Title 
        {
            get{ return v_title; }
            set{ v_title = value; }
        }
        
        public string Artist
        {
            get { return v_artist; }
            set { v_artist = value; }
        }
And it has to be this way:
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Artist { get; set; }

I don't undstand the difference...

Comment: @Robert: the difference is that the broken way, you've declared the members as `static`. That means that there's only one instance of the member, in the class itself, not in any instance of the class. When you switched to properties, you also removed `static`, which was actually the important part. That allowed each object instance to have its own values, not shared with all the others (in fact, in VB.NET, these members are labeled `Shared` and not `static`...seems more descriptive to me, though granted not consistent with C#'s own predecessors).

Comment: Thank you very much, I really got it this time. Thanks to all of you :)